# What would be a sufficient studio flash setup for my product photography?

Tags: lighting, product-photography, studio

In the past I've found some very helpful information here regarding how to proceed with my product photography, and you've all helped me a lot, so thanks!

Now, as I'm moving on towards studio flash equipment, I am wondering if what I'm being suggested is the right choice, and what a right pick would be in general. I'm attaching images and links for everything so that you can see. I have the table you can see below, and on it I'll be taking pictures of shoes & bags. I will also be using the same equipment (without the table), to photograph invisible ghost mannequins for clothing. What I see is that with this kit I don't have lighting on the back of my plexi glass and below it, which is really important. Should I simply fetch two of these sets, or do I have better options?

Thank you in advance.

Studio lights I am proposed: [Studio Lights](http://www.henrys.com/84841-METZ-MECASTUDIO-BL-400-SB-SB-KIT-II.aspx#)
My table: [image]

Answer (score 1):

The Metz is a starter studio set, but it might suit your needs very well.

Other options in a similar price range are Elinchrom D-Lite, Impact (B&H Branded strobes), Dynalight (re-branded versions of RimeLight from Korea) and a host of others you can find at B&H and Adorama.

Check their used equipment too. Sometimes you can score a great deal on a pro set for 20% and more off from new.

You should also look at Paul C. Buff. They have inexpensive kits that rival the top of the line flash systems for a fraction of the price.

Sounds like you won't travel with the flash, so durability might not be an issue.

It takes a little research to find what is right for your budget and your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do better. Adorama has a 300 w/s Flashpoint kit with two lights, stands, and umbrellas for less than $250. You could get two of these plus a set of wireless triggers for less than the cost of the Metz kit, and you would have a four light setup that would allow you a great deal more freedom. Search for SKU FPLFBF300K2 to see what I'm talking about.